# How can I calculate the difference between two date time values in the format yyyymm using excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use the following formula,

`INT(LEFT(A4,4) & TEXT((DATEVALUE(MID(A4,6,3) & " 1")),"mm"))=INT($C$1-1)`

`INT(LEFT(A4,4) & TEXT((DATEVALUE(MID(A4,6,3) & " 1")),"mm"))` this part returns date in format yyyymm.

$C$1's value is inputted by a user in the format yyyymm.

I want to compare it with the latter part but it fails if the value of $C$1 is set to 202101, for instance, please find the picture attached. I want the final output to be true in this situation.

[image: example]

Is there a way to modify the latter part/better to approach this problem?

Comment: =B1-A1 usually works as long as B1 has the date in the future cf A1.

Comment: In your comments to one of the submitted answers you stated you want the different to be display 202012.  Since that is the value of one of the two dates and the other value is different, can you explain how you arrive at this expected outcome?

Comment: I want 202012 as the final outcome. I just used the formula stated in one of the questions and tried to work-around that to get what I expected but apparently I didn't.

Comment: I want the formula to return 202012 when we subtract 1 from 202101.

Comment: Please put a picture containing cell data, there should be a more concise way.

Comment: FYI taking the difference between two dates, and subtracting 1 from the date are two different operations.

Comment: I have edited and added picture in the question as requested for clarity.

Comment: FYI `A4` to which your formula references appears very empty in you screen shot.  Did you mean A2 by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question by the following minor tweak in my current formula,

```
INT(LEFT(A4,4) & TEXT((DATEVALUE(MID(A4,6,3) & " 1")),"mm")) = IF(RIGHT($C$1,2)="01", INT($C$1-89), INT($C$1-1))
```

The latter part of the formula that is `INT(LEFT(A4,4) & TEXT((DATEVALUE(MID(A4,6,3) & " 1")),"mm"))` returns me a yyyymm. So if $C$1 was `202101` it would first check the two characters from right if it is "01", if it is true then it would subtract 89 from it hence resulting `202012`. And it works for all other cases I think. Obviously, if there need be to see `202011` instead of `202012`, then the formula would change to,

```
    INT(LEFT(A4,4) & TEXT((DATEVALUE(MID(A4,6,3) & " 1")),"mm")) = IF(RIGHT($C$1,2)="01", INT($C$1-90), INT($C$1-2))
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the comments by the OP to the original question.  OP requested that 1 be subtracted from the date 202101 to give 202012 as the answer.

Assuming the string date is in C3 and the value to subtract is in D3, use the following formula in E3:

```
=IF((RIGHT(C3,2)-D3)>0,LEFT(C3,4)&RIGHT("0"&(RIGHT(C3,2)-D3),2),RIGHT("000"&LEFT(C3,4)-1,4)&RIGHT("0"&RIGHT(C3,2)+12-D3,2))
```

This should work provided:

- It is not year 0
- No more than 12 months is being subtracted

[image: POC]

## UPDATE

Since the question has new information.  Use the following formula in B2

```
=A2=--IF((RIGHT(C1,2)-1)>0,LEFT(C1,4)&RIGHT("0"&(RIGHT(C1,2)-1),2),RIGHT("000"&LEFT(C1,4)-1,4)&RIGHT("0"&RIGHT(C1,2)+11,2))
```

If you are unsure if the value of A2 is going to be a number stored as text or an actual number, you can tweak the above formula with the following:

```
=--A2=--IF((RIGHT(C1,2)-1)>0,LEFT(C1,4)&RIGHT("0"&(RIGHT(C1,2)-1),2),RIGHT("000"&LEFT(C1,4)-1,4)&RIGHT("0"&RIGHT(C1,2)+11,2))
```

[image: POC II]

Comment: `INT(LEFT(A4,4) & TEXT((DATEVALUE(MID(A4,6,3) & " 1")),"mm"))=INT($C$1-1)`

`INT(LEFT(A4,4) & TEXT((DATEVALUE(MID(A4,6,3) & " 1")),"mm"))` this part returns date in format yyyymm.

I want to compare it with the latter part but it fails if the value of $C$1 is set to 202101, for instance, it returns 202100 when it should return 202012. Is there a way to modify the latter part/better to approach this problem?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can, in two steps.

Step one, convert the text value to the date

```
=DATE(MID(A1;1;4);MID(A1;5;2)+1;0)
```

when A1 is the date text value. It returns the last day of the month, which is very convenient for most calculations.

Step two

Once you get dates out of text values, do the difference, e.g. date2-date1 to get the output in days.

To convert the resulting date back to text string, use text formatting

```
=TEXT(C1;"yyyymm")
```

The actual formatting string depends on you regional settings of your system. See excel function TEXT help https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c for details.

In your question you perhaps were looking not for the difference, but for the comparison. In that case you could simply convert the text to the value as

```
=VALUE(A1)
```

and then compare the values.

```
=IF(VALUE(A2)>VALUE(B2);A2;B2)
```

Comment: When I convert `202101` to date, I get `31/01/20` when it should be `31/01/21`

Comment: The OP was very clear on the input format, but the formula here works for a different one.

Comment: @Enigmativity - my bad, the formula was amended.

Comment: @royalewithcheese sorry the formula was slightly off, I corrected it.

Comment: I want the difference to return `202012`

Comment: `=TEXT(VALUE(DATE(MID(E6,1,4), MID(E6,5,2) +1, 0)) - VALUE(DATE(MID(D6,1,4), MID(D6,5,2) +1, 0)), "yyyymm")` I wrote this and I got 190001 as the output